# Automatic VCS/Cloud Sync with history

Tags: file-synchronization, git, version-control, cloud-storage

In my life i store sources in cvs, svn, git, google drive, dropbox, flashdrive, smartphone sdcard... I understand today why i always want to migrate to another system. They all don't let me forget about them!

All i want is simple:

1. "Sync" all, include new files in choosen folder automatically. Except files and folders explicitly marked "don't sync"(it's important to).
2. Sync changes automaticaly on save.
3. Changes history. Some ability to restore some previos state.
4. Works on windows.

So i want a kind of automatic comfortable vcs for dummies. I don't need anymore all another "pro" vcs stuff, because i prevent the reason of it. :)

I try this :

- google drive and dropbox don't exclude subfolders and no workable history.
- git and other vcs always forget to add or commit some files. I change workplace 2 times per day, if forgot something it's very frustrating.
- i want to try gitless.com but it seems no windows support.

Any suggestions and advises highly appreciated!

Comment: Your description somehow reminds me of [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) (which I planned to try for quite a while but could not find time for yet). There are plenty of videos on Youtube on it. And it has an easy [assistant](http://git-annex.branchable.com/assistant/) (see intro video there). Works cross-platform, even on Android :)

Comment: If it fits: be welcome to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) :)